# How to execute a command that is built as string

Tags: r

I am looking to build strings, that should be the input for executing a command. The string is ready and constructed as described below.

**Question:**

How can I send the content of the string as a command?

```
# Build list with content
my_list <- list("no1" = 12)

# Define content, parts of string.
text_left  <- "ls.str("
text_right <- ")"

# Build string.
test_string_result <- paste0(
  text_left,
  "my_list",
  text_right
)

# Result of string.
print(string_result)
```

The printout of command "print(string_result), gives:

`[1] "ls.str(my_list)"`

**Wanted result:**

I want the "string_result" to be the base for sending the content as a command, 
e.g. it should send "ls.str(my_list)

Comment: `eval(parse(text = test_string_result))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `eval(parse(text=print(test_string_result)))`

Results in:

```
no1 : num 12
```